# How can I broaden my range of skills at home and what kinds of things are worth learning?

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, performance

I'm a first year IT student in uni and have a dev job in which we use a lot of .Net, sql and a bit of js. I want to be able to broaden my range of skills so I have more to offer for current and future employers but I'm not sure what skills would be most useful.

For context I've worked with SQL, .Net, a bit of JS, HTML, python (although I learned to code using python and I haven't revisited it for a while), and some MongoDB. Keep in mind that I never got a chance to set up these bigger projects, only ever worked on well established programs and never was a part of the rollout process.
(keep in mind I am open to learning other areas such as higher level math if that would help - I did a bit of the higher level maths in high school but ultimately did the standard level math)

What skills should I learn at home to try and progress and what are some good ways of practising these? (sorry for how general the question is)

Comment: For inspiration, could have a look at some statistics from the [SO 2021 survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2021#section-most-popular-technologies-programming-scripting-and-markup-languages).

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the field you are interested in. Here are some of my favorite technologies

- web frontends: Vue3.js, Bootstrap5
- web backend: Django
- data analysis: R, Python, Tensorflow
- image processing: OpenCV (Python wrapping)
- desktop GUI: PyQt5
- embedded, IoT: C/C++

I know, it is a bit biased towards Python, but the thing is that this language can be used in so many fields that it is worth considering.

If you are going to start one of these, always start with a little project, maybe following some good tutorial. Hands-on is the way forward.